# Theory of Computation - Showing that a language is regular

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, regular-language

I'm reviewing some notes for my course on Theory of Computation and I'm a little bit stuck on showing the following statement and I was hoping somebody could help me out with an explanation :)

Let A be a regular language.  The language B = {ab | a exists in A and b does not exist in A*}
Why is B a regular language?

Some points are obvious to me.  If b is simply a constant string, this is trivial.  Since we know a is in A and b is a string, regular languages are closed under union, so unioning the language that accepts these two strings is obviously regular.  I'm not sure that b is constant, however.  Maybe it is, and if so, then this isn't really an issue.  I'm having a hard time making sense of it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prove by construction: Give a regular expression that recognizes B. The class of regular languages is closed under union, concatenation, star, and complement.

Answer (score 4):

The `a` and `b` in the question are not constant strings but any strings, and B is the language of strings with the beginning of the string in A and the end of the string not in A. Now, since any regular language can be recognised by a regular expression, if `Ra` is the regular expression to recognise the language A, then `Ra` concatenated with the “`not Ra`” regular expression is the regular expression to recognise the language B. Since B can be recognised by a regular expression, it's a regular language.

Edit: I initially missed the star after the A at the end of the definition of B in the question. To account for it, make the part of the regular expression that recognises `b` also include the star.

Comment: Or, to put it more directly, regular languages are closed under complement and concatenation, and `ab` is the concatenation of a regular language with its complement.

Answer (score 0):

B is a regular language because it is language that ends when a input "b" appear.
we can write a regular expression for the given language B as a*b